# output of 'iptables -L -nv' commands meaning

Tags: unix, iptables

`root@linux #iptables -L -nv`

The output looks like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 89658 packets, 116M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 122K   97M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       192.168.43.104       0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 70753 packets, 70M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 141K   61M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.43.104
```

what relation between `Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 89658 packets, 116M bytes)`
and below that line.
and `Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 70753 packets, 70M bytes)`
and it's below the line.

I get confused what is 70753 packets vs 141K pkts and 70M vs 61M

Comment: And by the way, the description of the tag `iptables` starts with: _GENERAL IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com._

Comment: if its 'OFF-TOPIC' why the hell you have tags like iptables?? ahahhaha  :-/

Comment: If you read the description of the tag: _Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables._

Answer (score 0):

Chain INPUT means how much traffic you have received
Chain OUTPUT mean how much traffic your machine sent to the network.

Thus the request to the WEB page will create outgoing traffic(OUTPUT counters will be increased) and after WEB server reply you will receive incoming traffic(INPUT counter will be increased)